# CSS: is there a way to insert the content of an attribute as text in my output?

Tags: css, css-paged-media, antenna-house

Normally, CSS works by matching element names in the HTML:`p.heading1 {}` affects all elements of type p with class heading1.

Is there a way to display an object/text that only exists as an attribute?

For example, this is my HTML:

```
<body var="text I want to insert">
    <div class="titlepage"> 
        <p class="titlepagetext">this should also be displayed</p>
```

The title page has a number of `<p>` children. In addition to them, I want to display the content of body/var on the title page.

Comment: _“It displays the contents of @var”_ - don’t see how, not even the selector matches: `.titlepage[var]` - you have no element with the class `titlepage` that has an attribute `var`. And not sure what you mean with the rest of it either, _“but the formatter ignores the p.titlepagetext and all other children of div.titlepage”_ - who is “the formatter”, and in what way is it “ignoring” those elements?

Comment: `content` only applies to pseudo-elements like `:before` and `:after`...try that.

Comment: **but** using `content` for *actual content* is not recommended.

Comment: CSS does not have a parent selector so there is no way to get `var` within the child

Comment: What they said. Also, 1) `var` is not a good name for an attribute. If it helps, think of all attribute names without dashes as reserved for future use. 2). You missed a closing quote at the end of var. 3) Not sure what any of this has to do with CSS paged media. 4) `font:20pt` is an error; you meant `font-size`.

Comment: It might be better if you explain what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than asking for help with a specific way of achieving it. The question isn't clear, but if I'm understanding it right, then the answer is no, you can't do that in CSS, and it probably wouldn't be good practice even if you could. But if you explain why you're trying to do it, we might be able to point you in the direction of the right way to do it.

Comment: I've cleaned up the question. Code was simplified too much. Formatter = Antennahouse Formatter, which I use to convert the HTML+CSS into PDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably consider [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). The custom property will get inherited by all the elements inside the body and you can use pseudo element to display it where you want:

```css
.titlepage:before {
  content:var(--var);
}
```

```html
<body style="--var:'text I want to insert'">
  <div class="titlepage">
    <p class="titlepagetext">this should also be displayed</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: using .titlepage:before, the content displays along with the <p>. Can't use variables (limitation of Antennahouse Formatter), but I can get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

AH Formatter has an `-ah-attr-from()` extension function that will let you get the contents of an ancestor's attribute (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#attr-from).

You could use `-ah-attr-from()` in a rule for `.titlepagetext::before`.

Answer (score -2):

When you using css, you can't target parent. There is no way to get parent selector. And content: `""` can apply only for pseudo-classes.

Comment: First-class comment pillager …